# Searching active directory doesn't pull up the user record when applying a specific filter

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, directorysearcher

```
DirectoryEntry deEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com");
DirectorySearcher dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(deEntry);
dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))";
```

When I apply that filter, the user doesn't show up. But I've checked his attributes and those properties have those values.

But when I add his last name in the filter, he *does* show up.

```
dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(sn=harper))";
```

Here is a picture with the deubg info that shows that his attributes are set correctly.

[image]

I have no idea what's going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "harper");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Yeah, the app was made in 3.5, but it's a few years old. I'll look into this to see if it can be used. I generally don't want to look for a single user. The app is looping through all of the users. Which I'm sure System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement can handle that, but I'm not fond of remaking that whole portion for this.

Comment: Decided to just redo that section with this method. Thanks!